# Processing a list in XSLT

Tags: list, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have list of elements in variable

```
|ELEMENT1|ELEMENT2|ELEMENT3|ELEMENT4|ELEMENT5|
```

If any of request elements matches this , I should display local name and its value.

Request XML :

```
<Root>
<element1>Test1</element1>
<child>
    <element2>222</element2>
</child>
<secondChild>
    <element2>234</element2>
</secondChild>
<thirdchild>
    <element3>5w2</element3>
</thirdchild>
</Root>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/> 
<xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="list"><xsl:value-of select="'|ELEMENT1|ELEMENT2|ELEMENT3|ELEMENT4|ELEMENT5|'"/></xsl:variable> 

<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(translate($list,$lower,$upper),concat('|',translate(local-name(),$lower,$upper),'|'))]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),':',.,'|')"></xsl:value-of>            
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output :

```
element1:Test1|element2:222|element3:5w2|
```

But I am getting

```
element1:Test1|element2:222|element2:234|element3:5w2|
```

This is because I have element2 in two places in XML. I should not read second element2 while processing.

Can you please help on this

Comment: "*If any of request elements matches this , I should display local name and its value.*" That's exactly what it does. "*I have element2 in two places in XML. I should not read second element2 while processing.*" Why not? What is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

Filter out any elements that have a preceding element of the same name.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" /> 
  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:variable name="list" select="'|ELEMENT1|ELEMENT2|ELEMENT3|ELEMENT4|ELEMENT5|'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[
      contains(
        concat('|', translate($list, $lower, $upper), '|'),
        concat('|', translate(local-name(), $lower, $upper), '|')
      )
    ]">
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[local-name() = local-name(current())])">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ':', ., '|')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a key

`<xsl:key name="name" match="*" use="local-name()"/>`

and then in your condition you check

`<xsl:for-each select="//*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('name', local-name())[1])][contains(translate($list,$lower,$upper),concat('|',translate(local-name(),$lower,$upper),'|'))]">`